# Space of all functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, frechet-derivative

I have been studying calculus of varitions and one of the first things I came across was the functional derivative. When I looked for additional information and resources on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) was that when the space of functions is a Banach space, the derivative is actually something called the Frechet derivative, which directly generalizes ordinary calculus.
A question then popped in my mind - *can we define a space of **functionals** to be a Banach space?* Of course, every function is a functional, so we could just put only functions therein, but I want to consider some nontrivial cases, preferably those, wherein the action functional $S[q]=\int^b_aL[t,q(t),\dot q(t)]$ is contained. And what will be the Frechet derivative of such space (if it exists)?

Comment: There is the directional derivative $\nabla_u S[q] = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{S[q+\epsilon u]-S[q]}{\epsilon}$, as a function of $u$ it is a linear map $X \to \mathbf{R}$, the second derivative is a linear map $X \times X \to \mathbf{R}$ and so on.